# Unable to cast HLS Live streaming in android

Tags: chromecast, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I want to cast HLS Live stream to Cast Device using Cast Companion Library Android. I try the url but failed to play on Cast Device. When using VOD HLS URL, the video can play on Cast Device.

I already change the streamType: MediaInfo.Builder(url).setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)

Or anything else I must change ?

This is the Live stream URL I want to cast: http://live.streamingfast.net/livech1.m3u8

How to cast HLS Live stream using Cast Companion Library Android? Please help...???

Thanks

Comment: What receiver are you using? You need to show what error you get in the receiver (turn on logging).

Comment: For this i am using Styled Media Receiver and didn't get any error in log.

Comment: how did you setup your basic app? I am not able to cast any video, there is nothing helpful to stream on cast using cast sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run into such issues, you need to turn on debugging in the console to see what the issue might be. If you do so, you'll notice that your streams lack the required CORS headers:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://live.streamingfast.net/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/live-ch1-3.m3u8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`